# How to influence to another component in React (add dynamically child)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm new in React, please help.

I have three components   `<Square / >`, `<Line / >`, `<Cell />`.

And I have next structure `<Cell />` in `<Line / >` - `<Line / >` in  `<Square / >`

In component `<Square / >` I have a button and `onClick` in it.

When I click Button, One more `<Cell />` component should be added to `<Line / >` Component.

How can I do it?

Sorry if it is simple, I just learning.
Thanks

Bellow is my code

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <td>
    <div className="square__cell"></div>
   </td>
  );
 }
}



class Line extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <tr>
    <Cell />
   </tr>
  )
 }
}





class Square extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <div className="square">
    <table className ="square__table">
     <tbody>
      <Line />
     </tbody>
    </table>

    <button className="square__button square__button_append square__button_col-append"
      onClick={()=>{alert(1)}}>
    </button>

   </div>
  );
 }
}





ReactDOM.render(
  <Square />,
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the common ancestor of your components to hold some state defining the cells (in the snippet below I use simple strings.). The state is then mutated by that component alone, by giving callbacks to its children if necessary. Please note that I construct an entirely new list on each setState, and don't just change the state object. This is a core concept in React and you should feel comfortable with it before you try more complex things.

Then you want your components to render the children that you give them and/or be able to render a list. Here I decided to put it all in Square, but it would probably be better to give the list to `<Line>`to render. In my snippet, Line is entirely unnecessary.

```js
class Cell extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <td>
      <div className = "square__cell" >{this.props.children}</div> </td>
    );
  }
}

class Line extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <tr>{this.props.children}</tr> )
  }
}

class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.state = {cells : []}
  }
  addCell(){
    let oldCells = this.state.cells,
        cells = oldCells.concat(["cell-" + oldCells.length]);
    this.setState({cells});
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div className = "square" >
      <table className = "square__table" >
        <tbody >
          <Line>
            {this.state.cells.map(
              (cellName) =>{return <Cell>{cellName}</Cell>;}
            )}
          </Line>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <button className = "square__button square__button_append square__button_col-append"
      onClick = {() =>this.addCell()} >add a cell</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render( <
  Square / > ,
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]
);
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div />
```